# Undefined function in expression

Tags: vb.net

when i update the access database record i get this error(Undefined function (the first item) in expression).here is my code

```
Try
    d.Dataedit(String.Format("delete from ptsense where PT_Date=#{0}# and PT_Code={1}", Textdate.Text, Textcode.Text))

    If listselect.Items.Count > listres.Items.Count Or listselect.Items.Count = listres.Items.Count Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To listselect.Items.Count - 1
            d.Dataedit(String.Format("insert into ptsense(PT_Name,PT_Date,PT_Code,sample,G,coun,comm,organism,sens)values('{0}',#{1}#,{2},'{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}')", txtname.Text, Textdate.Text, Textcode.Text, Comsample.Text, Comstain.Text, Txtcount.Text, Txtcomm.Text, Comorganism.Text, listselect.Items(i).ToString))
        Next
        For i As Integer = 0 To listres.Items.Count - 1
            d.Dataedit(String.Format("update ptsense set resist={0} where PT_Date=#{1}# and PT_Code={2}", listres.Items(i).ToString, Textdate.Text, Textcode.Text))
        Next

    Else

        For i As Integer = 0 To listres.Items.Count - 1
            d.Dataedit(String.Format("insert into ptsense(PT_Name,PT_Date,PT_Code,sample,G,coun,comm,organism,resist)values('{0}',#{1}#,{2},'{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}')", txtname.Text, Textdate.Text, Textcode.Text, Comsample.Text, Comstain.Text, Txtcount.Text, Txtcomm.Text, Comorganism.Text, listres.Items(i).ToString))
        Next
        For i As Integer = 0 To listselect.Items.Count - 1
            d.Dataedit(String.Format("update ptsense set sens={0} where PT_Date=#{1}# and PT_Code={2}", listselect.Items(i).ToString, Textdate.Text, Textcode.Text))

        Next
    End If


Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: that errors comes from the access database not from visual basic. Place your formatted query in a string and only then pass it to d.Dataedit(). this will allow you to easily put a breakpoint on it, just before you send it to the method, and see the EXACT query that causes your headache. if still haven't found it, post here the exact query.

Comment: what is the difference

Comment: easier to help you if you add the EXACT update query you're sending to d.Dataedit() to your question, most likely you'll figure out exactly whats wrong once you see it.

Comment: this error comes from the update query not insert query

Comment: there is something not right in your update query, you need to copy it to here (AFTER its formatted), thats why im asking for the RAW query, with the data in the parameters. for all i know you could be doing something like string.format("update {0}", "--; the first one")

Comment: For i As Integer = 0 To listres.Items.Count - 1
                    Dim str As String = (String.Format("update ptsense set resist={0} where PT_Date=#{1}# and PT_Code={2}", listres.Items(i).ToString, Textdate.Text, Textcode.Text))

                    d.Dataedit(Str)
                Next

Comment: nothing happen i get thesame error

Comment: paste here the EXACT raw query, after formatting. without {0} and {1}s , the values them selves.